# Data validation for preventing blank entries

Tags: java, beginner, validation

I want to create a validation wherein blank entries will not be accepted. So if I call this code:

```
entry[i].setName(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Name: "));
if the entry is blank, it will not be accepted and an error will prompt:
```

it cannot accept blank entries. Of course it could easily remedied with this code:

```
String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Name: ");
 while (name.equals("")){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot accept blank entries!");
       name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Name: ");
 }
```

but if I want to validate 100 fields that I don't want to have a blank entry, then my code will be messy and long.

How could I do it better? I've read about using getters and setters or the try-catch methods to do the validation but I don't know if this kind of validation is applicable. And I don't know how I can do it. And if it is applicable, would I be violating the Model-View-Controller concept if I included a `JOption` message dialog box on my getter and setter methods? What code does programmers usually use in doing blank entries validation?

Answer (score 5):

Extract the input code into a method:

```
String getNonBlankInput(String prompt) {
   String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(prompt);

   while (input.equals("")) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot accept blank entries!");
      input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(prompt);
   }

   return input;
}
```

Usage:

```
String name = getNonBlankInput("Enter name: ");
```

Answer (score 3):

You should really look at the java validation standard, specifically JSR303.

[Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html) is the reference implementation, take a look at [their documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/reference/en-US/html/).

To provide a simple example

```
public class Foo {
    @NotNull(message = "property bar must be provided")
    @Pattern(regexp = "[a-z0-9]", message = "property bar must contain only letters and numbers")
    private String bar;
}

ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
validator = factory.getValidator();

Foo foo = new Foo();

Set<ConstraintViolation<Foo>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(foo);
// now you have a Set of ConstraintViolations, if something is not working
```

Use the existing standards, no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: You misunderstand the question, he never speak about hibernate. So before making ugly comment with your wheel, try to understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

Please change the validating condition like this.

```
while ("".equals(input.trim())) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot accept blank entries!");
      input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(prompt);
}
```

This type of validation may also check only blanks as input & any other value also.

```
1. String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Name: "); contains spaces.
2. String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Name: "); contains null.
```